# Xml Node value never change error

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, zoho

I got this xml from calling Zoho Crm api: https://ix-infiniti-preview.azurewebsites.net/Manage/zohotest.xml

I wanted to loop through each row of this xml and create a DataTable row data with each row. This is what I came up with:

```
            //Get List of fields
            List<string> fields = data.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                 .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                                 .ToList();

            List<MalformedLineException> exceptions = new List<MalformedLineException>();
            List<string> values = new List<string>();

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);

            // Count number of row returned
            XmlNodeList xmlNL = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row");
            int rowCount = xmlNL.Count;

            for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
            {
                DataRow currentRow = data.NewRow();
                XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/response/result/" + moduleName +"/row[@no='" + row + "']");
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                {
                    foreach (string field in fields)
                    {
                        XmlNode objNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("//FL[@val='" + field + "']");
                        if (objNode != null)
                        {
                            string value = objNode.InnerText;
                            currentRow[field] = value;
                        }                       
                    }                   
                }
                data.Rows.Add(currentRow);
            }
            data.EndLoadData();
```

This piece of code works fine for row 1 and map all the values to DataColums perfectly. But when it comes to row 2 (and 18 other rows in the actual xml) all the values of these rows will be exactly the same with row 1. So basically I got 20 of row 1 displayed as a result. Not sure what is going on here please help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: What does fields look like? Where is yuur definition of "data"?

Comment: Have you tried instead of data.Rows.Add(currentRow); using data.LoadDataRow(currentRow, true); ?

Comment: Why don't you use the 'xmlNL' node list and use a foreach to loop through those nodes?

Comment: data.Rows.Add(currentRow); is in the wrong place. Needs to be one loop further in. Your superfluous loop doesnt help.

Comment: Looping through xmlNL is not that I want. Because I have to get all the nodes in <row no="1"> then <row no="2"> ... till the end of the xml. So basically it's like divide the xml into 20 equal pieces --> 20 Data Table row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant fully test this until I have your definition of fields.

```
        // You will need to ensure these are right
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        List<string> fields = new List<string>()
        {
            "LEADID", "SMOWNERID", "Lead Owner", "Company", "First Name", "Last Name", "Email", "Phone", "Lead Source", "Created By", "SMCREATORID", "MODIFIEDBY", "Modified By", "Created Time", "Modified Time", "Street", "City", "State", "Zip Code", "Last Activity Time", "Lead Type", "Practice name", "SMS Opt Out", "Send SMS"
        };

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn(field, typeof(String));
            data.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        string xmlText;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            IWebProxy defaultWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
            defaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            client.Proxy = defaultWebProxy;

            xmlText = client.DownloadString(@"https://ix-infiniti-preview.azurewebsites.net/Manage/zohotest.xml");
        }

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlText);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/response/result/Leads/row");

        foreach (var row in xnList)
        {
            XmlElement item = row as XmlElement;
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Attributes["no"].Value);

            DataRow currentRow = data.NewRow();
            List<string> rowData = new List<string>();
            foreach (XmlElement node in item.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (fields.Contains(node.Attributes["val"].Value))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["val"].Value + ":" + node.InnerText);

                    currentRow[fields.IndexOf(node.Attributes["val"].Value)] = node.InnerText;

                }
            }
            data.Rows.Add(currentRow);
        }

        data.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: List<string> fields is simply a list of val attribute of each FL node. e.g. LEADID, SMOWNERID, Lead Owner, Company, First Name, Last Name

Comment: What I want to achieve is that I have to get all the nodes in <row no="1"> then <row no="2"> ... till the end of the xml. So basically it's like divide the xml into 20 equal pieces --> 20 Data Table.

Comment: No I still receives back 20 of row 1 displayed

Comment: When I debug through the code I notice xn in xnList has definitely changed their value into different row. But when it reached "string value = objNode.InnerText;" somehow value is always equal to the value of row 1 so I ended up having 20 of row 1 displayed

Comment: Your XPath is wrong. You are selecting ALL elements that have that attribute value and because its SelectSingleNode you only get the first one back. Let me play with the xpath.

Comment: Ive changed the answer and it definitely outputs the data from each row not just the 1st. Cant get the DataTable to accept the changes though.

Comment: OK fixed it. Typo on my behalf.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. I can see 20 rows returned now :)